# Batch Removal of "Where from" Metadata Without a Handler

Tags: terminal, finder, applescript, script, metadata

I have many images that contain the "Where from" metadata in the "get info" section that shows the URL where they were downloaded from. I want to remove this information from all of them at the same time.

I created an Applescript that works when the shell script retrieves one image from the selected folder in finder. But when the shell script result is multiple images, I get the following error:

> xattr: No such file:

I need the Applescript to work without the use of a handler since it will be used in an application that does not accept handlers.

```
tell application "Finder" to set selectedFolder to selection as alias list
set folderPath to quoted form of POSIX path of selectedFolder

set getImages to "mdfind -onlyin " & folderPath & " 'kMDItemKind = *image'"
set selectedImages to paragraphs of (do shell script getImages)

set filePaths to {}
repeat with thisFile in selectedImages
    set end of filePaths to quoted form of POSIX path of thisFile
end repeat

do shell script "xattr -d com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms " & filePaths
```

Comment: Passing more than one selected folder to this workflow will cause an error on the second line. While AppleScript is reasonably savvy at dealing with a `list` containing a single string and, where necessary, knowing when to use the `string` rather than the `list`, it isn't able to do this with any list of two or more items. Neither `POSIX path` nor `quoted form` are properties available to a `list` so both are going to complain if you make them try and deal with anything besides the trivial case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add:

```
& space
```

To:

```
set end of filePaths to quoted form of POSIX path of thisFile
```

Example:

```
set end of filePaths to quoted form of POSIX path of thisFile & space
```

---

Another way to resolve this issue is to coerce the *list* `filePaths` to a *string* before it's used in the `do shell script` *command*, as after all it does get coerced in the process.

So, just before the `do shell script "xattr ...` *command*, do the following, instead of using `& space` as previously mentioned:

```
set text item delimiters to space
set filePaths to filePaths as string
set text item delimiters to ""
```

Comment: Wow! I can't believe it was that easy. After hours of searching all I needed to do was add "& space". Thank you so much.

Comment: @David, It took me longer to write up the answer then to see what was wrong with the _code_. :)

Comment: That what happens when you mix a newbie with Applescript. Simple mistakes like this happen to me all the time. I only have one month learning it so I will get better with time :-)

Comment: @CJK, Having a surplus whitespace dangling is not going to hurt anything in this instance. Also, off the top of my head I cannot think of one command line utility that is going to baulk about a single space character after the last argument.

Comment: @user3439894 It would suffice just to insert `set text item delimiters to space` before the `do shell script` line, where the coercion will occur regardless. Although, doing it explicitly as your addendum lays out makes it crystal clear what is happening.

Comment: @CJK, I'm well aware of that!